# Access denied for user root@localhost

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I installed phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu LAMP 18.04.

Now, when I visit `/phpmyadmin/` and try to login with username `root` and the password that I set up when installing phpMyAdmin, I get the following error page:

[image]

I have a file in the directory `etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php` which contains the following information:

```
$dbuser='root';
$dbpass='THE_PASSWORD';
$basepath='';
$dbname='phpmyadmin';
$dbserver='localhost';
$dbport='3306';
$dbtype='mysql';
```

I tried logging in using `phpmyadmin` as my username and I could get in. However, logging in as `phpmyadmin` does not give me enough privilege to create a database.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the root mysql user is restricted to disallow certain logins so for example in my environment on the command line issuing:

`mysql -u root -p mysql`

won't let me connect to the database, I would have to sudo:

`sudo mysql -u root -p mysql`

If you want to grant more privs to the phpmyadmin user then mysql logon as root and issue the relevant grant commands so for example the following gives the user all privs to all databases in all tables, including being able to grant privs to other users:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Of course you might not want that level of grant, you might want to only grant to certain databases/tables.

Comment: Thanks @codlord. :)

I was able to access the database using command line. However, I want to access it using a web interface by visitng `/phpmyadmin/` in the browser. Is there a way to do that? Using `root` and my password does not work in the browser.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible but it's not recommended to use the root user for front-end stuff, for security you want to be using a different user with the least-amount of privs needed. So I would suggest giving the phpmyadmin user whatever privs you need or create another user and give that privs. I don't know what you would do to make a root login possible via phpmyadmin as I've never done it.

Comment: Thanks @codlord. I created a new user with a different password to login. It allowed me to create the database.

Comment: is the user `phpmyadmin` created automatically? I don't remeber creating it. I was once asked some name so I entered `phpmyadmin` but I thought it was for the URL I need to type to access `phpMyAdmin`. :)

Comment: Not that I know of, the phpmyadmin create_tables.sql creates the database and tables but not a user. The comments at the top say that it expects user "pma" to exist but I just run the create_tables.sql then created a phpmyadmin user and granted privs.