# I can't install PhpMyadmin after upgrade from Ubuntu 19.04 to 20.04 via 19.10

Tags: 20.04, phpmyadmin, migration

For the life of me, I can't figure out what the problem is even after trawling the Internet for possible solutions for hours. No obvious solution has worked. So there goes.
On Ubuntu 19.04 I installed Mysql and phpMyAdmin to manage a Kodi centralized database. After the upgrade to 20.04, Mysql was bumped to

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

I still have root access to MySQL and the Kodi clients connect to the movie database without a problem. So I decided to install phpMyAdmin but realized I had to add a PPA (can't remember which one now) since PMA is no longer in the repos. After a few unsuccessful attempts during the configuration script I ended up removing the phpMyAdmin database and user within MySQL thinking then I could do a fresh install of PMA. But it has not solved my problem. I keep having this error message:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Remember I can access the Mysql server with user root without a problem:

```
xbmc@nas-extras:~$ mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8714
Server version: 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

These are the existing databases:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| MyMusic56          |
| MyMusic60          |
| MyMusic66          |
| MyMusic67          |
| MyMusic68          |
| MyMusic69          |
| MyMusic70          |
| MyMusic72          |
| MyVideos107        |
| MyVideos108        |
| MyVideos109        |
| MyVideos110        |
| MyVideos112        |
| MyVideos113        |
| MyVideos114        |
| MyVideos116        |
| MyVideos99         |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| nextcloud          |
| performance_schema |
| specialfeatures    |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
23 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

And the existing users:

```
mysql> SELECT User FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+
| User             |
+------------------+
| kodi             |
| debian-sys-maint |
| mysql.infoschema |
| mysql.session    |
| mysql.sys        |
| nextcloud        |
| root             |
+------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

PHP version:

```
xbmc@nas-extras:~$ php -v
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: May  5 2020 12:14:27) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
xbmc@nas-extras:~$
```

Apache version:

```
xbmc@nas-extras:~$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2020-04-13T17:19:17
xbmc@nas-extras:~$
```

Any pointers, help would be much appreciated. And I am willing to provide more info if need be.

Comment: Did you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490647/phpmyadmin-installation-error-1045-acces-denied-using-password-no ?

Comment: I think I did... at some point. This is what I get when I try to blank the password:
`mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';

ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements`

Comment: This is because I chose a mix of capital letters, numbers and special characters > 8

Comment: See here also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239154/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost/1239167#1239167

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem with a few pointers. Thanks to those who took the time. These are the steps I followed to manually install PhpMyadmin:

From a mysql console:

- create user *phpmyadmin*

`CREATE USER 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';`

- Grant privileges (you might not want that level of grant):

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

- Create database with the SQL query *create_tables.sql* from PhpMyadmin download (resides in folder **sql**):

  `mysql -uroot p<pass> < create_tables.sql` (I know it's not safe but...)
- Run configuration again, skipping creation of *phpmyadmin* database.

  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin`
  You should now be able to connect to the web interface. Done.

If you have the two error messages:

**mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

and

**connection to controluser as defined in your configuration failed**

you might need to edit another file to solve a password discrepancy between mysql and PhpMyadmin:

`sudo nano /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php`

and make sure you type the password you defined when creating the user *phpmyadmin* from within the msql console:

```
$dbpass=password_defined_in_mysql
```

Problem solved for me.